# What does pdfmake return on successful generation of pdf or on failure?

Tags: pdfmake

I am using [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/) to generate pdf documents. pdfMake.createPdf() method returns undefined. How to find out if createPdf() completed successfully or if it failed? 
One way is to check if the file exists in the location it is supposed to be created in. Is there a smarter way?

Thanks,
Harsha

Answer (score 0):

If it's not too late...
I'm using PDFMake in angular 4 and using pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition) is returning an object which you can use to download/open/print you'r pdf.

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).print();
```

you can use this code to know when it's done:

```
pdfMake.createPdf(dd).download('file.pdf', () => {
        console.log("success");
    });
```